# Using Java 8 with Google App Engine SDK

Tags: java, google-app-engine, java-8

What is the issue in using Java 8 along with Google App Engine SDK? The Google App Engine SDK is separated from my application, which means that I'm using only the API, regardless of how they are implemented. In the same way, we can use an API that use Python language in a Java project.

What can't I use an API that is implemented by Java 7 on a Java 8 project?

Comment: you can use java8 on Flexible VM

Comment: @IgorArtamonov, what do you mean by Flexible VM?

Comment: I mean type of App Engine VM, there're two of them: Standard VM and Flexible VM. See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/

Comment: @IgorArtamonov, the doc tells that "It is not recommended for production use."

Comment: yes, Flexible VM is still in beta

Comment: Java 8 on App Engine standard is in beta today: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/runtime-java8. Please note: this is BETA, with NO SLA to back it up, but you should be able to start using it for hobby or for experimenting.

Comment: Google App Engine standard now supports Java 8

Answer (score 0):

Of cource, Google App Engine doesn't support Java 8. If you want use Java 7 in project with Java 8 is no problem. If you want use Java 8 in Java 7 projects is bad solution. If you want use dependencies (Google App Engine SDK) in your JDK 8 project, that is normal. If you want know all features of Java 8, then read here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-whats-new-2157071.html

Answer (score 0):

Calling the APIs is not the problem: e.g. you can have a Google Compute Engine with Java 8 installed and your Java 8 app can call the APIs.

But the problem is that AppEngine only supports [Java 7](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9537) and thus it does not understand your Java 8 application:
e.g. It is the same, as if you want to start your Java 8 app on a PC where only Java 7 is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 cannot be used with the App Engine standard environment at this time though much work is being done to bring this support soon.  The App Engine feature request for [Java 8 support](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9537) is the issue to track for this.

In the meantime, one can use the flexible environment to deploy a [Java 8 application](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/quickstart) though this is currently in Beta.

Please note that one cannot use Java 8 with the standard environment because the App Engine SDK and the runtime use Java 7.  When building your application, they are built together and then deployed.  This is why they must all be using Java 7.